# jquery keypress/keydown to call function

Tags: jquery, html, input, keypress, keydown

my previous question:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819713/jquery-store-input-value-into-empty-array-element)

sweetamylase posted her fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/jSyfy/ , which is great and very close to what I am trying to achieve, but I am having trouble getting it so that pressing enter will trigger the same as clicking the button.

I tried this and other variations

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
       FoodDispaly();
    }
});
```

but haven't gotten it to work

Comment: Need more code to understand what exactly is going on here. Make a jsFiddle with your code and then post that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I've always had problems with keypress. Use keyup instead. I've modified the fiddle linked to you in your first post to handle keyup:

```
$("#inputFoodChoice").keyup(function (e) {
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
                    e.preventDefault();
                    checkInputValue(e);
                }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jSyfy/1/

Answer (score 1):

To go with your problem, add this right after the button click handler:

```
$("#inputFoodChoice").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        checkInputValue();
    }
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jSyfy/2/